# Flash performance loss in Internet Explorer when wmode is transparent or opaque

Tags: flash, apache-flex

For some time we've been seeing very poor performance with our flash content (2 reasonably large flash/flex applications) in IE when the wmode is "transparent" or "opaque". Google searches yielded no usable results, nor did profiling and optimizing our codebase for perfomance and low memory usage. What could we have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd post this here to save others the time:

The culprit turned out to be a IE-only css statement that was used to add a dropshadow to IE 7 and 8, wich was added to our site recently.

```
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#999999, Strength=3,
Direction=90), 
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#999999, Strength=3, Direction=180),
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#999999, Strength=3, Direction=270)\9;
```

This can seriously hinder flash performance, so if you are facing simular performance problems which are specific to IE, be sure to check.